# Redundant storage of select files and synchronization between multiple computers

Tags: sync, filesystems, raid, file-sharing, software-raid

Historically, I've manually copied personal files onto multiple hard drives periodically to keep them backed up, but I just emptied my wallet getting certain files that were only stored in one place (because they were so large I didn't have space to duplicate them) recovered from a hard drive that failed. I'm hoping to prevent this from ever happening again.

My goal is **not** to run my whole operating system on a RAID - I just want a certain set of personal files on a 2TB drive to be synchronized with a second external drive. Furthermore, to take advantage of the expense of two drives storing files redundantly, I'd appreciate it if there was a way to set this up such that my system could leverage faster read/write times by sharing the load between both disks, and keeping them mirrored while i/o is idle.

Building on this system, I want to be able to have offline availability of a subset of these files (Documents, Pictures and Music, but not videos) on any of 3 home computers. If a file is changed locally on any machine, which later reconnects to the network, I'd like changes to these files to be synchronized back to the main 'server'.

I'll do my best to illustrate my goal. Pardon the MSPaint art.
[image]

I'm using windows machines primarily, so for the offline file synchronization, I wouldn't be surprised if there's a built in windows service. As for maintaining a RAID 1 using an external, though, I'm completely in the dark. I'm somewhat familiar with operating systems running on top of a RAID, but really what I want is a 2TB external drive that is mirrored with a drive built into the PC, but can still be disconnected so that I can travel with my files, and re-connect it at a later date to restore the RAID.

Perhaps a RAID format isn't the ideal solution here. Maybe just some software that constantly synchronizes files between multiple directories. A huge plus would be if I could do this while the 2TB external is formatted as a FAT32, so that I could still connect it to Gaming systems, etc.

*EDIT*
I think "Offline Files" will satisfy my need for remote file access from machines other than my "server", but in terms of the RAID 1 setup, is there any way I can experience read performance improvements at the same time? Seems a shame to waste 2TB and get nothing other than fault tolerance out of it.

Comment: I just realized I won't be able to set up these mirrored drives with a FAT32 file system because they don't support files >= 4GB. I might as well just format them as RAID 1 in that event. True?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the following [off-site](http://forums.cnet.com/7726-6121_102-2023840.html?tag=posts;msg2023840):

> I watched for years as people tried
>   RAID 1 to save their behinds from
>   failed drives. Sadly I never found it
>   to pay off in decades. The issues of
>   user error, virus, pest and worms
>   actually made RAID 1 a liability since
>   many (misinformed) owners thought it
>   was a backup in realtime. Yes, it was.
>   As soon as an error occurred it was
>   faithfully duplicated in the RAID 1
>   mirror drive.
>
> To double the trouble the owner who
>   thought it was a backup discontinued
>   making backups offline to tape or
>   disks.
>
> I'm sure there is one success story
>   out there but in decades I've never
>   encounted one.
>
> -> If you had RAID 5 I will write I've seen that work, but they had a few
>   dozen drives on that system.
>
> Maybe it's time to give up RAID 1 for
>   speed and occasionally backup.

In my case, I have very little fear of viral activity or user error resulting in data loss, only hardware failure. Still, it looks like I wouldn't even get a read performance enhancement out of creating a RAID 1, so perhaps my best solution is just to manually back up one 2TB external on the other once in a while?

Answer (score 2):

### Rsync

If "constantly synchronised" can be relaxed to "periodically synchronised" (say once an hour) you could use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) ([*nix](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/),  [Windows](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650)) or one of it's derivatives like duplicity or a similar tool like [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

### Live Mesh

You might instead be able to use [Windows Sync Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Working-with-network-files-when-you-are-offline) or "Offline files".
Windows [Live Mesh](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mesh?os=other) may be what you are looking for.

### Similar Questions

- [Synchronize Laptop and Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/64526/synchronize-laptop-and-desktop)
- [What application can I use to synchronize several machines devices?](https://superuser.com/questions/201007/what-application-can-i-use-to-synchronize-several-machines-devices)
- [How do I synchronise two folders in real-time in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/65524/how-do-synchronize-two-folders-in-windows-7-in-real-time)
- [How to manage and synchronize data on 7 separate computers](https://superuser.com/questions/107941/how-to-manage-and-synchronize-data-on-7-separate-computers)
- [How to synchronize the home folder between multiple computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/31512/how-to-synchronize-the-home-folder-between-multiple-computers)

Comment: I think "Offline Files" will satisfy my need for remote file access from machines other than my "server", but in terms of the RAID 1 setup, is there any way I can experience read performance improvements at the same time? Seems a shame to waste 2TB and get nothing other than fault tolerance out of it.

Comment: "With appropriate operating system support, there can be increased read performance, and only a minimal write performance reduction." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#Standard_levels. That's the extent of my knowledge of RAID 1 tuning :-)